# argument out of range parameter name index

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, textbox, arguments, flowlayoutpanel

**since i have the code of the auto generated text box**

[Insert data from auto generated textbox to SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56970533/insert-data-from-auto-generated-textbox-to-sql-server-database)

i am try to write a code for ensuring of the auto generated text box in FlowLayoutPanel1 contain data

the auto generated text box build depends on the number in **Val(Label2.Text)** of the real part

and if any text box is null or empty then the process will stop until fill all fields

the auto generated text box will be like this if the **Val(Label2.Text)**
is equal to **3**

so i try this  in the **save button**

```
  Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click


    For k As Integer = 1 To Val(Label2.Text)

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls(i).Text) Then
            MsgBox("Error , fill all text box")

                Return
            Else
                UpdateUsers()
                i += 1

            End If


    Next



    MsgBox("Done , add all data to database ")
    Button3.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

**so i getting error after leave some text box and back to fill it again**

[image]

and the all of form code is

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
'library for create folders
Imports System.IO

Public Class part

    Dim cLeft As Integer = 1
    Dim top1 As Integer = 5
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim path1 As String

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand



    Public Sub AddNewTextBox()
        Dim txt As New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()

        txt.Top = cLeft * 30
        txt.Left = 100
        'txt.Text = "TextBox " & Me.cLeft.ToString
        cLeft = cLeft + 1
        txt.ForeColor = Color.White
        txt.BackColor = Color.Gray
        txt.Font = New Font("Arial", 14.0, FontStyle.Regular)
        txt.Size = New Size(350, 31)
        txt.Location = New Point(156, 130 + top1)
        txt.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center

        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txt)
    End Sub



    Private Sub part_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'college part number
        Label2.Visible = False
        'college path folder
        Label3.Visible = False


        For m As Integer = 1 To Val(Label2.Text)
            AddNewTextBox()
            top1 = top1 + 35
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateUsers()
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Hazim M\Desktop\stud_project\stud_project\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO college_part ([name],[coll_of_part],[part_path]) Values (@name,@coll_of_part,@part_path);", cn)
                If i < Val(Label2.Text) Then
                    path1 = Label3.Text & "\" & FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls(i).Text.Trim & Date.Now.Year
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls(i).Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@coll_of_part", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Label1.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@part_path", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = path1
                    cn.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    cn.Close()

                    If Not Directory.Exists(path1) Then
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(path1)
                    Else
                        MsgBox("folder is existing")
                    End If

                End If

            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click


        For k As Integer = 1 To Val(Label2.Text)

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls(i).Text) Then
                MsgBox("Error , fill all text box")

                    Return
                Else
                    UpdateUsers()
                    i += 1

                End If


        Next



        MsgBox("Done , add all data to database ")
        Button3.Enabled = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

thank u

Comment: I believe you need to use a zero based index in VB.NET: `For k As Integer = 0 To Val(Label2.Text) - 1`

Comment: This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5450740/3484879) seems relevant.

Comment: @Dan Guzman thank u , but getting same error see this image [image](https://i.ibb.co/kB5Ld5R/3.png)

Comment: @HazimMohammed, it seems the value entered on the form exceeds the actual size of the collection. Consider validating the value before attempting iteration: `If FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count > Val(Label2.Text) Then …`

Comment: thank u @Larnu i think the error with index by **(i)** counter in  FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls(i)

Comment: @HazimMohammed, yes. That's why you need to validate that the specified `Label2.Text` does not exceed the size of the collection before attempting the iteration. Otherwise, you will get the error.

Comment: This was why I suggested using the Tag property in my answer to your previous thread. If you would have then you could have used a For/Each loop using the same Controls.OfType method only checking if the Tag is not null: `For Each txtBox As TextBox in FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)` and then the check: `If txtBox.Tag IsNot Nothing Then`

Comment: TBH, most of this code can go which in return would fix many of the issues I see already and some that *could* and *will* eventually become an issue/maintenance problem.

Comment: @David  thank you for your help,  in your answer how is my code will be , if you can share to me the all correct in answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move dim i Integer=0 to local variable in the Button3_click method. ANd Pass i to the UpdateUser call (add the param to UpdateUser). The current global i keeps adding 1 and eventually out of range.